# tex capacity exceeded using the lstlisting package

Tags: miktex, memory

Using the lstlisting package on a large number of items (200 +) I get

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=3174358].<argument> \XC@@tmp \FPsub{\scratch}{1}{\scratch} %
```

I have absolutely no clue if there is a way for me to increase this pool size, and if there is, how.
Am using MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: This error USUALLY is the result of an infinite loop, so the first thing you need to try is to isolate the part of the code causing the problem.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Did that. I refrained from posting an ME because it would have been a document containing 250 pieces of code (each being a standalone document containing one or more tikzpicture environments) presented in an lstlisting environment and the .pdf pictures they produced. Each code compiles correctly and produces the picture as expected. At any rate, the lstlisting environments would be expected to just list source code, whether that code is kosher or not. Error occurs after about 220 listings, regardless of exactly what item that is. Splitting the lot into 2 documents works fine.

Comment: names of input files are stored in the pool, and that space isn't released when the input is complete.  if the names are long, it should run out of space earlier.  you might try substituting some really long names for the first few inputs to verify this.  (i believe that someone addressed this problem, though not on this list; i will try to remember where i have seen it, perhaps in tugboat.)